TypeError: Object of type Response is not JSON serializable, when sending a patch request to update user data
When using flask I try to send a patch request to update user data but get a TypeError message instead which I cant seem to figure out why.
Here's the relevant part of my code...
class UpdateUser(Resource):
    def token_required(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
            token = request.headers.get('Authorization')
            if not token:
                return jsonify({'error': 'Token is missing!'}), 403
            try:
                token = token.split(" ")[1]  # Assuming 'Bearer <token>'
                data = jwt.decode(token, app.config['SECRET_KEY'], algorithms=['HS256'])
                return f(*args, **kwargs, current_user_id=data['sub'])
            except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
                return jsonify({'error': 'Token has expired!'}), 403
            except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
                return jsonify({'error': 'Invalid Token!'}), 403
        return decorated_function

    @token_required
    def patch(self, id, current_user_id):
        if id != current_user_id:
            return jsonify({'error': 'Unauthorized'}), 401

        user = User.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
        if not user:
            return jsonify({'error': 'User not found'}), 404

        data = request.get_json()
        if '_password_hash' in data:
            hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(data['_password_hash'].encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt()).decode('utf-8')
            user._password_hash = hashed_password

        for field in ['fname', 'lname', 'email', 'user_role']:
            if field in data:
                setattr(user, field, data[field])

        try:
            db.session.commit()
            user_dict = user.to_dict()
            return jsonify({'user': user_dict}), 200
        except Exception as e:
            db.session.rollback()
            app.logger.error(f"Error during updating user: {e}")
            return jsonify({'error': 'Internal Server Error'}), 500

api.add_resource(UpdateUser, '/user/<int:id>')

and i guess my model for good measure
class User(db.Model, SerializerMixin):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fname = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    lname = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    user_role = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    phone_number = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    _password_hash = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    reset_password_token = db.Column(db.String)
    reset_password_token_expiration = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now())
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, onupdate=db.func.now())

    libraries = db.relationship('Library', backref='user')
    product_metrics = db.relationship('ProductMetric', backref='user')

    @property
    def password(self):
        return self._password_hash 

    @password.setter
    def password(self, password):
        self._password_hash = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt()).decode('utf-8')

    def authenticate(self, password):
        return bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf-8'), self._password_hash.encode('utf-8'))

    @validates('email')
    def validate_email(self, key, email):
        assert '@' in email, 'Invalid email address'
        return email

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<User(id={self.id}, email='{self.email}')>"

    serialize_rules = ('-created_at', '-updated_at', '-libraries', '-product_metrics')


Edit: Here's my full traceback error message
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2024 09:35:25] "OPTIONS /user/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[2024-08-19 09:35:27,293] ERROR in app: Exception on /user/1 [PATCH]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chernandez148/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 880, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/chernandez148/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 865, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
  File "/home/chernandez148/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 493, in wrapper
    return self.make_response(data, code, headers=headers)
  File "/home/chernandez148/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 522, in make_response
    resp = self.representations[mediatype](data, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/chernandez148/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_restful/representations/json.py", line 21, in output_json
    dumped = dumps(data, **settings) + "\n"
  File "/home/chernandez148/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/home/chernandez148/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/home/chernandez148/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/home/chernandez148/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Response is not JSON serializable
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2024 09:35:27] "PATCH /user/1 HTTP/1.1" 500 -

I'm not sure why im getting the error, even when it's actually updating my database, Whelp anyone can give is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Please add the full traceback of the error.

of course , thank you!

Right now there is no way to check without looking at the request you are sending, Resource class or any middlewares you use. But it seems that somewhere in the code you try to:
jsonify(jsonify({some response data here}), status_code)

Because of first jsonify already returns a Response, the second throws an exception that type Response is not JSON serializable. Double check the code to be sure that you don't try to create a response twice.
